# Comportamiento inesperado con ( user-threads | fibers | coroutines )

Tags: c, hilos

Estoy probando [**libcoro**](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libcoro.html), una librería muy simple y de bajo nivel que proporciona **coroutines** *mas o menos portables*. Supuestamente, es válida para sistemas en producción.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "coro.h"

// Argumentos pasados a los 'thread's.    
struct Arg {
  const char *message;
  coro_context coro;
  struct coro_stack stack;
};

// Datos de cada 'thread'.
// Args[0] es el 'thread' principal, en el que empezamos y que controla
// al resto.
struct Arg Args[4] = {
  { NULL, { 0 }, { 0 } },
  { "Mensaje 1", { 0 }, { 0 } },
  { "Mensaje 2", { 0 }, { 0 } },
  { "Mensaje 3", { 0 }, { 0 } }
};
// Selector del 'thread' actual; usado al planificar.
volatile int idx;

// 'cuerpo' de los 'thread's.
void body( struct Arg * );
// Manejador de la interrupcion SIGALRM.
void handler( int );

int main( void ) {
  // Reservamos la memória a usar como pila por cada 'thread',
  // y los inicializamos.
  for( idx = 1; idx < 4; ++idx ) {
    coro_stack_alloc( &( Args[idx].stack ), 0 );
    coro_create( &( Args[idx].coro ),
                 (coro_func)&body,
                 (void *)&Args[idx],
                 Args[idx].stack.sptr,
                 Args[idx].stack.ssze );
  }

  signal( SIGALRM, &handler );
  idx = 4;
  coro_create( &( Args[0].coro ), NULL, NULL, NULL, 0 );

  // Planificador.
  // Los ejecutamos en secuencia, del último al primero.
  while( --idx ) {
    printf( "Dentro del bucle. idx = %d\n", idx );
    alarm( 1 );
    coro_transfer( &( Args[0].coro ), &( Args[idx].coro ) );
  }

  printf( "Fuera del bucle. idx = %d\n", idx );
  return 0;
}

void body( struct Arg *arg ) {
  printf( "%s.\n", arg->message );
  while( 1 );
  coro_transfer( &( arg->coro ), &( Args[0].coro ) );
  printf( "Saliendo de body. idx = %d", idx );
}


void handler( int sig ) {
  (void)sig;
  coro_transfer( &( Args[idx].coro ), &( Args[0].coro ) );
}
```

En un código similar que usé de esqueleto, que no usaba `alarm( )` ni `signal( )`, ni el `while( 1 )` (sin forzar por tanto el cambio de tarea en el manejador de interrupciones), producía la siguiente salida:

> Dentro del bucle. idx = 3
>   Mensaje 3.
>   Dentro del bucle. idx = 2
>   Mensaje 2.
>   Dentro del bucle. idx = 1
>   Mensaje 1.
>   Fuera del bucle. idx = 0

La salida *esperada* del código mostrado es la misma; los mensajes en pantalla deberían ser idénticos; no obstante, se muestra lo siguiente:

> Dentro del bucle. idx = 3
>   Mensaje 3.
>   Dentro del bucle. idx = 2
>   Mensaje 2.

Ahí se detiene, y el uso de la CPU se pone al 100%; es decir, se detiene en el `while( 1 )` dentro de la función `body( )`; da la impresión de que no entra en la función manejadóra de la interrupción.

Estoy seguro de que el fallo está en mi lógica de funcionamiento, pero no doy con la *tecla*. Es raro que *interrumpa* el `while( 1 )` 2 veces y luego deje de Hacerlo. Mi sentido común dicta que, o no lo interrumpiría nunca, o lo haría siempre.

Comment: Sin tener ni idea de libcoro... Eres consciente de que `while(1)` introduce una espera infinita que impedirá que se ejecute el resto de la función `body`, verdad?

Comment: Para eso el manejador de interrupciones. Es un intento de *limitar* eso que comentas, y lo hace bién. Interrumpe el `while(1)` 2 veces; pero debería hacerlo 3. Eso es lo que me choca, es como si dejara de recibir la señal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, ya está. Error por mi parte, al no leer correctamente la documentación de libcoro.

La librería ofrece varios *backends*, para usar uno u otro dependiendo de la plataforma, el sistema operativo, o por si alguno directamente no funciona.

Estaba haciendo las pruebas con el *backend* `CORO_ASM`, supuestamente de los mas rápidos en Linux. La última modificación de libcoro fué en 2016, así que asumí, erroneamente, que ese *backend* funcionaria en sistemas modernos.

Los he probado todos, y, en mi plataforma (Linux, x64), tan solo funciona con `CORO_CONTEXT`. Por los síntomas, parece que hay alguna incompatibilidad con el manejo de señales.

Ya lo avisa en la documentación:

> -DCORO_ASM
>
> Hand coded assembly, known to work only on a few architectures/ABI: GCC + arm7/x86/IA32/amd64/x86_64 + GNU/Linux and a
>   few BSDs.
>   Fastest choice, if it works.

La mas rápida ... si funciona.